# Query range with utcdatetime X++

Tags: axapta, x++

I've some problems with queries in X++.

```
Query extended range failure: SPLCertificateSell.ValidFrom is not a valid datasource.field pair near pos 36.
```

I try to to a QueryBuildRange with an utcdatetime but I get an error ('validFrom' is a dateTime and 'DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime()' returns an utcDateTime):

```
qbrCertificateSell2 = qbdsCertificateSell.addRange(fieldNum(SPLCertificateSell, ValidFrom));
    qbrCertificateSell2.value(strFmt('( (%1.%2 <= "%3") )'
                                      ,tableStr(SPLCertificateSell)
                                      ,fieldStr(SPLCertificateSell, ValidFrom)
                                      ,DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime()
                                      ));
```

Comment: Try changing the line to this `qbrCertificateSell2 = qbdsCertificateSell.addRange(fieldNum(SPLCertificateSell, RecId));`

Answer (score 1):

You need convert `UTCDateTtime` to `System.DateTime` try this function: `Global::utcDateTime2SystemDateTime()`

For example, in your code:

```
qbrCertificateSell2 = qbdsCertificateSell.addRange(fieldNum(SPLCertificateSell, ValidFrom));
qbrCertificateSell2.value(strFmt('( (%1.%2 <= "%3") )'
                                  ,tableStr(SPLCertificateSell)
                                  ,fieldStr(SPLCertificateSell, ValidFrom)
                                  ,Global::utcDateTime2SystemDateTime(DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime())
                                  ));
```